# Automatique Arguments naming in overridden methods

Tags: java, netbeans

This might be a weird question, but it could help me alot, 
when overriding a method (using "Insert Code.."), netbeans puts some random arguments names, for example:

```
public void setValueAt(Object o, int i1, int i2)
```

while it should be(using the naming in the doc)

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
```

can this be done in Netbeans? (other compilers do[like eclipse])

thank you.